# Scope of variables in Qt vs vanilla c++

Tags: c++, qt, scope

Disclaimer: I am total newbie to Qt.

Let's assume we have a byte array returned from a function `innerFunc` that is later used in another function `outerFunc`.

```
QByteArray innerFunc(){
 QProcess ls;
 ls.start("ls", QStringList() << "-1");
 return ls.readAll();
}
void outerFunc(){
 QByteArray gotcha = innerFunc();
 .
 .
 .
}
```

In vanilla c++ I would expect `readAll` function to return a pointer that needs to be deleted later. In Qt this function returns an instance of the `QByteArray` class so I guess it shouldn't be accessed outside of the `innerFunc`'s scope.

If so, how should I properly transfer the data to an outer function? Should it copied to `QByteArray *tmp = new QByteArray` or is it unnecessary?

Comment: this will all be covered in any decent c++ textbook - qt is behaving just like "vanilla c++"

Comment: "_In vanilla c++ I would expect readAll function to return a pointer that needs to be deleted later._": No, that is what you would expect in C, but in C++ that would be considered a bad design whether Qt or not. It is the whole point of RAII, one of the major concepts differentiating C++ from C, that destructors should take care of this implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have looks fine.  `QByteArray` is like `std::vector<uint8_t>` or `std::string` and not like a pointer.  It manages its own memory.  It's fine to return it from a function or pass it to a function by value.  The compiler will take care of copying and/or moving the data from one object to another as appropriate, using the contructors/operators defined by the QByteArray class.

- [QByteArray header file](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/text/qbytearray.h?h=dev)
- [QByteArray documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html)